# How do I add a class name to pager attribute in Yii's widget?

Tags: php, yii, pagination, yii-widgets

This is my table in Yii:

```
$this->widget('GridView', array(
        'dataProvider' => $users,
        'itemsCssClass'=>'table',
        'pager' => array(
                'class'             => 'CLinkPager',
                'prevPageLabel'     => 'Previous',
                'nextPageLabel'     => 'Next',
                'htmlOptions'       =>  array(
                                            'class' => 'btn btn-info'
                                        )
        ),
        'columns' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'User ID',
                'type' => 'raw',
                'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data["id"])'
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'Username',
                'type' => 'raw',
                'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data["username"])'
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'Name',
                'type' => 'raw',
                'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data["name"])'
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'Email',
                'type' => 'raw',
                'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data["email"])'
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'Role',
                'type' => 'raw',
                'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data["function"])'
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'Status',
                'type' => 'raw',
                'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data["active"])'
            ),
            array(
                'name'  => 'Action',
                'type'  => 'raw',
                'value' => 'CHtml::link("<button  type=\'button\'  class= \'btn btn-info user_ajax\' data-toggle=\'modal\' data-target=\'#myModal\'>Info</button>")',
            ),
        ),  

    ));
```

I have a pagination and it is working, what i want to  is to add a class name from bootstrap to each **li** generated. Now with this example the classes **btn** and **btn-info** is added to **ul**. What should I changed ? thx

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found a solution: I was missing a pager property

```
'pager' => array(
                'class'             => 'CLinkPager',
                'prevPageLabel'     => 'Previous',
                'nextPageLabel'     => 'Next',
                'header' => '',
                // 'htmlOptions'        =>  array(
                                            // 'class' => 'btn btn-info'
                                        // )
                'previousPageCssClass' => 'btn btn-info btn-sm',
                'selectedPageCssClass' => 'btn btn-warning btn-sm',
                'internalPageCssClass' => 'btn btn-info btn-sm',
                'firstPageCssClass' => 'btn btn-info btn-sm',
                'nextPageCssClass'  => 'btn btn-info btn-sm',
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `'hiddenPageCssClass'` and `'selectedPageCssClass'` properties of the pager

```
'pager' => array(
                'class'             => 'CLinkPager',
                'prevPageLabel'     => 'Previous',
                'nextPageLabel'     => 'Next',
                'hiddenPageCssClass'=>'notselected', // set it for page buttons that are not selected
                'selectedPageCssClass'=>'selected', // set it for the current page button
                'htmlOptions'       =>  array(
                                            'class' => 'btn btn-info'
                                        )
        ),
```

To check more properties click [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLinkPager)